# Julia dataframe : Deleting row from sub dataframe

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

Problem statement : deleting row from sub dataframe

Code:

```
x=[rand(3) for i in 1:3]
dfx=DataFrame(x,:auto)
dfy=@view dfx[2:3,:]
```

Q: I want to delete first row from dfy so it will be deleted from dfx too.
I do subset of original dfx to make further checking of subsetted rows if they fulfill conditions. At the end I want to decide to keep row in dfx or to delete it. I operate on subset of dfx which is dfy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to perform row deletion in views. Here is one example showing why it would be problematic:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:3)
dfv = 3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     2
   3 │     3

julia> dfv = view(df, [1, 1, 1, 1], :)
4×1 SubDataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     1
   3 │     1
   4 │     1
```

and now assume you want to remove rows 2 and 3 from the `dfv` view, but you cannot remove the row from the parent twice and also after such a deletion what would be the state of `dfv`?

> I do subset of original dfx to make further checking of subsetted rows if they fulfill conditions.

Note that you can use `parentindices` function to get the indices in the parent of your view, so that you can later remove appropriate rows from the parent.

#### EDIT

An example:

```
julia> x=[rand(3) for i in 1:3]
3-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [0.9362990387940191, 0.872386665989372, 0.9062520245175714]
 [0.31161625031197393, 0.21614040488877717, 0.7277794414244152]
 [0.35548885964798926, 0.4422493896149622, 0.45150837090448315]

julia> dfx=DataFrame(x, :auto)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1        x2        x3       
     │ Float64   Float64   Float64  
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.936299  0.311616  0.355489
   2 │ 0.872387  0.21614   0.442249
   3 │ 0.906252  0.727779  0.451508

julia> dfy=@view dfx[2:3, :]
2×3 SubDataFrame
 Row │ x1        x2        x3       
     │ Float64   Float64   Float64  
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.872387  0.21614   0.442249
   2 │ 0.906252  0.727779  0.451508

julia> row_to_remove = parentindices(dfy)[1][1]
2

julia> delete!(dfx, row_to_remove)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1        x2        x3       
     │ Float64   Float64   Float64  
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.936299  0.311616  0.355489
   2 │ 0.906252  0.727779  0.451508
```

Comment: I cannot find in my universe use for your case. I assumed that if I can edit values indirectly with dfv in df then  the delete action as edition will work too.  Your tip with parentindices worked for me fine. Thanks.

Comment: But in general other developers want such behavior, and this is what is supported and allowed in Julia Base for other views. We have to have a design that supports all workflows users might employ. Also - as commented - your problem can be solved using `parentindices`. I will add an example to show you how.

Comment: Ah - and a simple example of the use case is e.g. if you want to use bootstrapping of rows of a data frame (e.g. you build some predictive model and want to get bootstrapped confidence intervals for its parameters). In such a case you EXPECT to have duplicate rows in a view.

Comment: Thanks for help. It is perfectly fine for me.